# How to add data to a MutableArray after filtering data from the webservice in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I'm getting data from SOAP webservice. then add those data into a mutable array.this is my code of soap message

```
SoapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                   "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                   "<soap:Body>\n"
                   "<GetAirport xmlns=\"http://mobileapi.bbq.uk/\">\n"
                   "<Authkey>%@</Authkey>\n"
                   "<AirportCode>%@</AirportCode>\n"
                   "</GetAirport>\n"
                   "</soap:Body>\n"
                   "</soap:Envelope>\n"
                   ,AuthenticationKey, changewrd];
```

if `changewrd=@""`, then service returns all data. if `changewrd=@"a"` then service return all date which start from a.for changewrd I use `textfied.text`.So what I want is if user type a in the textfield then shoud add only the data starts from **a**,if user type **as** then olny add data start from **as**, not the the data include as.
because with this I want to build autocomplete textfiel. 
that means when user type **a**, should all names starts from **a** as code hint.then user select one from it. selected text should show as textfield.text. by filtering from the first point, I think it is easy.or if ther is any other way please get me know.this is how I add data.

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        Session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        DataTask = [Session dataTaskWithRequest:TheRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"data task with request error :%@", error);
                return;
            }
            if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    NSLog(@"data task with request, HTTP status code :%ld", (long)statusCode);
                    return;
                }
            }

            WebData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            [WebData appendData:data];


            ResultString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:WebData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            TagremovedString = [self stringbyStrippingXml:ResultString];

            NSError *Error;
            ResultData = [TagremovedString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            id dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:ResultData options:kNilOptions error:&Error];

            shortCode = [NSMutableArray array];
            fullAirport = [NSMutableArray array];

            for (NSDictionary *allAirports in dictionary) {

                First *first = [First new];
                first.fullAirport = [allAirports objectForKey:@"Airport"];

                NSLog(@"%@", first.fullAirport);


                [fullAirport addObject:first];

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            });

        }];
        [DataTask resume];

    });
```

get all data is sucess.no idea. I have stucked with this.hope your help.thanx

Comment: Hi bro, where you stucked?  you are already added objected into fullAirport array. what exactly do you want ?

Comment: Do you want to filter fullAirport , based on charecter began ?

Comment: what I want is to build a autocomplete textfield. 
that means when I type 'a', the airports begin from the a should give as autocmplete codehints under the textfield.
I have tried using two mutablearrays and textfield delegate methods.when I use static number of data it worked. but if I used this fullairport array, it gives errors

Comment: may I see the First class properties ? According to your code I can able to see fullAirport is one property. So you need to filter based on fullAirport value ? am I right ?

Comment: what I real want is to build a autocomplete textfield. when user type 'ab' the hints should be airports start from 'ab' ,not the airports that include 'ab'

Comment: First class has only NSString *fullAirport, and I can get mutablearry into a tableview successfully.I want ot build an autocomplete textfield

Answer (score 1):

use predicates

```
NSString *alphabet = "textfield text"// searching value

NSPredicate *pred =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.fullAirport beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
NSArray *filteredArr = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

filteredArr have all your filtered list

Comment: my array is nsmutabletype, should we use mutable copy with this

Comment: @subash are you able to filter ? do you have any issues ?